# Typo3 Extension: Tasks - scheduler or Task Center?

Tags: typo3, scheduled-tasks

I'm still new to Typo3 but I need to create an automatic daily task. When searching for tutorials two different things have come up:

- Task Center: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/taskcenter/DevelopersGuide/CreatingANewTask/Index.html
- Scheduler: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/DevelopersGuide/CreatingTasks/Index.html

...which should I be focusing on? I'm assuming task center creates a list of tasks but I would need something like the Scheduler extension to actually run them, whereas Scheduler lets me create and schedule tasks? Or have I got it wrong :S

The task will involve truncating a table, converting a csv file to mysql data and processing the SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Task Center is used for backend editor's task, e.g. "create a new user in the backend for this specific domain".

Scheduler is used for "low level" tasks, especially things not bound to a user or the backend, e.g. running a batch job, cleaning a cache database etc.

"Automatic and Daily" probably points to scheduler.

(Actually the very first sentence in the introduction of the docs you referenced, states this)

Comment: The task will involve truncating a table, converting a csv file to mysql data and processing the SQL. It's not technically a back end process as the data doesn't involve actual Typo3 users so I guess Scheduler is the one to go for?

Comment: yep, please update the question with that information to help improve this for others